# Map not showing using Google Maps API for Business

Tags: android, api, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm migrating an app from Google Maps Android API v2 to Google Maps Android API for Business following instructions here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/config#migrate_an_existing_application

This should be very straightforward but unfortunately after replacing all the com.google.android.gms.maps references to com.google.android.m4b.maps, the app is compiling right but the map is not showing : I get a gray rectangle instead.

One possible reason (and actually one thing I don't understand so far) is that the API key is the exact same as the one I used for Google Maps Android API. Logically, there should be a personal code to enter somewhere, something like the Client ID / Crypto key I've been sent by Google.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Didn't you have to generate a new API key in the Google console when you move to Google Maos Android v2 API? Also, it's the service enabled in your console?

Comment: I have an API key, which indeed works with Google Maps Android API v2 but not with Google Maps Android API. And yes, the service called "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled in my console.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation link below ,
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/auth

there seems to be a hidden service named "Google Maps Mobile SDK service"
which will be enabled by Google Enterprise Support when you sign up for the Google Map Mobile SDK for Business.

Once we purchase Business licence, enable this service in our project 
and generate a Map V2 API key using same procedure for non business version
we should be able to see the tiles loading on Android Device.

**Note:This observation is only based on documentation link above and not an experimented one.**